# Who are the remaining King/Queenslayers?

Tags: game-of-thrones

We know in the show that

> Jon Snow

has done this and is still alive at the end of the series. Who else is a King/Queenslayer and is still alive at the end of the series?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See below for the complete list of royal deaths but to answer the question those who killed a King/Queen and are still alive are.

#### Little Birds (Arthur)

They planned out the kill on Margaery Tyrell and might not be dead.

#### Brienne of Tarth

Killed Stannis Baratheon.

#### Davos Seaworth

Was involved in the killing of Renly Baratheon.

#### Drogon

His actions killed Cersei Lannister.

#### Arya Stark

She killed the Night King.

#### Jon Snow

Killed Mance Rayder and Daenerys Targaryen, also his mother Lyanna Stark who was married to Rhaegar Targaryen died in childbirth giving birth to him.

#### Ellaria Sand

Her fate is unknown but she could still be alive, she killed Myrcella Baratheon and Doran Martell.

---

To be complete let's go through the full list of monarchs in the series.

1. **Aerys Targaryen:** Killed by Jaime Lannister at the end of Robert's Rebellion.
2. **Robert Baratheon:** Killed by a boar whilst hunting, planned by Cersei Lannister and carried out by Lancel Lannister.
3. **Joffrey Baratheon:** Poisoned by Olenna Tyrell at the Purple Wedding.
4. **Tommen Baratheon:** Killed by himself, thought he could jump from too high of a height.
5. **Margaery Tyrell:** Killed by wildfire explosion, planned by Cersei Lannister, carried out by the Little Birds (Arthur in particular, he's the one who stabs Lancel Lannister) and Qyburn.
6. **Stannis Baratheon:** Injured fighting Bolton forces, killed by Brienne of Tarth afterwards.
7. **Renly Baratheon:** Killed by shadow baby, planned by Stannis Baratheon and carried out by Melisandre and to some extent Davos Seaworth.
8. **Balon Greyjoy:** Pushed off a bridge by Euron Greyjoy.
9. **Euron Greyjoy:** Killed in a duel by Jaime Lannister
10. **Robb Stark:** Killed by Roose Bolton at the Red Wedding.
11. **Olenna Tyrell (Queen of Thorns):** Killed by Jaime Lannister after he gave her poison.
12. **Cersei Lannister:** Killed by a ceiling collapse, planned by Daenerys Targaryen (somewhat) and carried out by Drogon.
13. **Night King:** Killed by Arya Stark.
14. **Mance Rayder (King Beyond the Wall):** Killed by Jon Snow after Stannis attempted to burn him alive.
15. **Rhaella Targaryen:** Died from complications in childbirth whilst giving birth to Daenerys Targaryen.
16. **Daenerys Targaryen:** Stabbed by the pointy end of Jon Snow's dagger.
17. **Brandon Stark:** Still alive at the end of the series.
18. **Sansa Stark (Queen in the North):** Still alive at the end of the series.
19. **Yara Greyjoy (Queen of the Iron Islands):** Still alive at the end of the series.

Bending the rules a bit the following are princes/princesses so let's add them in too.

1. **Rhaegar Targaryen:** Killed by Robert Baratheon at the Trident.
2. **Elia Martell:** Rhaegar's wife, killed by Gregor Clegane.
3. **Viserys Targaryen:** Killed by Khal Drogo when he couldn't wear the crown.
4. **Myrcella Baratheon:** Killed by Ellaria Sand as revenge for Oberyn's death.
5. **Trystane Martell:** Killed by the Sand Snakes for the same reason as Myrcella.
6. **Oberyn Martell:** Killed by Gregor Clegane.
7. **Doran Martell:** Killed by Ellaria Sand.
8. **Ellaria Sand:** Presumably killed by Cersei Lannister or by Drogon/Daenerys Targaryen during their attack on King's Landing but could still be alive.
9. **Aegon Targaryen (Jon Snow):** Killed by Allister Thorne and other members of the Night's Watch. (Later resurrected).
10. **Lyanna Stark:** Died from complications in childbirth whilst giving birth to Aegon Targaryen (Jon Snow).

Comment: FWIW I'm aware it is a big stretch including Davos here.

Comment: if we're including these, can we also say that the Night king in the show killed a prince by killing the three-eyed raven?

Comment: @Termatinator In the show I'm pretty sure the 3ERs identity was left unknown.

Comment: left unknown, well kinda, he did have the traits of one tho but I know that's also a far stretch

Comment: @Termatinator The Night King is dead anyway so I'll leave it out of it, I'm already stretching it quite a bit in some places better not go too far with it!

Comment: Left out Lyanna Stark, who was presumably a queen or at least a princess, since she was married to Rhaegar Targaryen. She’s another one for Jon Snow’s impressive tally.

Comment: @MikeScott I toyed with adding her initially but decided against it because it was all done in secret but you have a point so added in.

Comment: +1 for pinning Lyanna Stark's death on Jon Snow further racking up the King/Queen kills.

Comment: _Daenerys Targaryen: Stabbed by the pointy end of Jon Snow's dagger._ He also killed her

Comment: Olenna is not a Monarch, Queen of Thorns is just a moniker, not a formal title.

Comment: @Amarth I’m well aware, it’s not the only case where I stretched the question.

Comment: No, please don't put Lyanna there bro.

Comment: I am happy you didnt forget the Boar.

Answer (score 11):

### Arya Stark

I may play on words, but she still kills the Night **King**.

Answer (score 9):

### No, there is at least one person more

#### Depending whether the victim is recognized as a king

Brienne of Tarth executed Stannis Baratheon after the Battle of Winterfell.

I believe we can consider Stannis as a king, there was a significant force that backed his claim (at least before the battle).

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Targaryen history, there's also:

1. **Maegor Targaryen:** Was technically killed by the Iron Throne but probably assassinated.
2. **Rhaenyra Targaryen:** Killed by Sunfyre and Aegon II.
3. **Aegon II Targaryen:** Poisoned.
4. **Daeron I Targaryen:** Traitorously killed by Dornishmen under a peace banner.
5. **Baelor Targaryen:** Could've been poisoned by his uncle, Viserys II, either for the good of the realm or for the throne.
6. **Viserys II Targaryen:** Could've been poisoned by his son, Aegon IV, so he could ascend the throne sooner.
7. **Maekar Targaryen:** Killed while putting down the Peake uprising (possibly crushed by a rock during the storming of Starpike).
8. **Aerys II Targaryen:** Explained above.